# Access url parameter from angular js

Tags: angularjs, url-parameters

How to access header values in angular js controller.
[image]

Need to access the value of 'p'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

`$location.search()` will give you an object containing a key named 'p'

Comment: I didn't suggest giving it an argument like you did. The doc says that that "When called with a single argument the method acts as a setter, setting the search component of $location to the specified value."

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location:

> ```
> // given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo   
> var searchObject = $location.search();
> // => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
> ```

So if you want get value of `p` it's just

```
$location.search().p
```